# WooCommerce coupons after taxes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Somewhere in WooCommerce 2.3 WooCommerce decided due some regulations that coupons only can be applied before taxes.

http://develop.woothemes.com/woocommerce/2014/12/upcoming-coupon-changes-in-woocommerce-2-3/

But, I have a client which only has to apply coupons to the total including taxes. But, this doesn't seem to be natively possible with WooCommerce trough some settings. Anyone has an idea how to hook into WooCommerce to modify this behaviour? It has to be for all the coupons.

Answer (score 1):

I've just found out that the client tried to enter the coupons inc VAT, and the shop is configured that prices are ex. VAT. This causes troubles that simulates what I asked above. Changing the coupons to prices Ex. VAT solves that.

Comment: Thanks! The changes are made within the coupons that can be found at `/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=shop_coupon`. Very glad that you answered your question. :)

Comment: I discovered the setting does not exist in WooCommerce, but was added in a plugin I was using (Germanized for WooCommerce), so the sad answer is, this is not possible without using a proper plugin.